# django-settings-export not passing variables

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.11 and [django-settings-export](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/django-settings-export), but it is not working for this view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def foo(request):
    return render_to_response('foo.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed changing `render_to_response` to `render`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def foo(request):
    return render(request, 'foo.html', {})
```

Checking Django documentation, [render_to_response is not recommended and will be deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

> This function preceded the introduction of render() and works similarly except that it doesn’t make the request available in the response. It’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future.